# Mutate using 2 dataframes and multiple conditions

Tags: r

I am having denials dataframe and a payment dataframe. I want to check if a denial has received how many payments and sum of it.

Conditions are denial and payment account id must be same and denial date < payment date.

i want these 'how many payments received' and 'sum of payments' as a seperate features in denials dataframe.

How to achieve this using dplyr mutate

Comment: Probably something like this:

   denial %>%
          join(payment, by = "id") %>%
          filter(denial_date < payment_date) %>%
          group_by(id) %>%
          summarise(payments_received = n(),
                             sum_of_payments = sum(payements))
         ungroup()

Comment: Hi! welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [here for guide on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [here for guide on making reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)